# poner listas del mismo tamaño

Tags: html, css

tengo una lista donde hay botones y quiero que todos tengan el mismo tamaño, y no se como.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí tengo el code donde tengo el div con el informe y el box con los botones:

```
<div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div style="display: inline-block;width: 100%;">
                        <div style="float:left">
                            <h2 class="box-title">Informes disponibles</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="informes">
                <ul class="treeview-menu">
                    @{ Html.RenderAction("ReportsMenuUser", "Home"); }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/552105/edit) y agrega el código en formato texto en lugar de usar screenshots. Así es más fácil depurar. Por otro lado, intenta darle un `width` de 25% a cada botón, quizás te funcione o quizás no, es difícil determinarlo sin tu código `CSS`.

Comment: perdón, lo hice sin pensar... e igual me sirvió mucho tu aporte, gracias.

Comment: No es necesario que te disculpes. En su lugar edita la pregunta siguiendo las [normas del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: No olvides aceptar la respuesta que te ha sido más útil, y tal como te han dicho, pulsa en [edit] tu pregunta para mejorarla. Subir código como imagen [es mala idea](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976), y no todos pueden verlas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puede que lo que busques sea min-width, minimo tendrán ese tamaño, pero si sobrepasa se hará más grande.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
  min-width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>aaaaaaaaa</li>
  <li>aa</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>aaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
  <li>aaaa</li>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
</ul>
```

Si lo que quieres es que se corte el texto y pase abajo tendrás que darle in ancho width fijo como en este ejemplo:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>aaaaaaaaa</li>
  <li>aa</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>aaaaaaaaa aaaa aaaa aaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa</li>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
  <li>aaaaaaaa</li>
  <li>aaaa</li>
  <li>aaaaaa</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo más con su comentario.